# Reference for Lemma 2 on Mean Value Theorem Wiki

Tags: reference-request, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I'm looking for a reference for Lemma 2 on the Mean Value Theorem Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorem_for_vector-valued_functions). I've also stated it below:

**Lemma 2**

Let $v:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$ be a continuous function on $[a,b]$, then we have that
$$ \left\Vert\int_a^b v(t)\,dt\right\Vert\leq\int_a^b\Vert v(t)\Vert dt. $$

Comment: What exactly are you looking for ? The proof is given in the wikipedia link. Notice that an alternative way to prove this is to derive it from the triangle inequality for finite sums, and the construction of Riemann integral as a limit of finite sums.

Comment: Yeah I know the proof is given there. But I would like to use the result in a paper I'm writing, so it would be nice to have a more 'formal' reference than wikipedia.

Comment: You can find it in Rudin's book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: In my first answer, I overlooked the multi-dimensional character of your question. It still seems quite standard.

One possible reference: Rudin, *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, Theorem 6.25